Application Insights not logging from console application
I'm trying to understand how logging to application insights works for simple logging from a console application. I have created a console app as follows, hosted it in Azure as a webjob and it runs. I can see from the logs that it's writing to the console but I can't see where to look in Application Insights to see the console logs. I want to be able to create an alert if there is an error.
Class LoggingEngine:[Logging Engine Class]

Program.cs:

In Azure App Services | WebJobs:

Clicked on the highlighted logs icon and get this: [Web Job Logs]

But when I go into Monitoring | Logs and run any of the queries they all say No Results.
Firstly, have I got my code correct?
Secondly, I'm using the F1 (Free) App Service Plan, does that matter?
Thirdly, Can you help me with a query for Application Insights to look at Console Logs please?
Fourthly, Do I need to enable Profiler to be able to see console writes?
Any help \ suggestions would be greatly received,
Thanks,
I have tried various versions of code that I've found regarding this but nothing seems to be logging. I don't know where I'm going wrong.

Welcome, please update your question with the code in text format so someone can assist you, otherwise nothing will happen on this question likely.  Although the pics of the gui console are okay, its code and error messages that are critical.

Check the transaction search in application Insights.

Change your configuration as shown in this SO sol.

How does your configuration file look? Can you please share.

You can see the logs in transaction search or in trace table in logs

If I were you, I'd try first to use the TelemetryClient class implemented by the Microsoft.ApplicationInsights NuGet package. Use the TrackTrace first and verify data is written in the traces table. After you've written something, give it some time - there's a delay up to 5 minutes, in my experience, between the moment the TrackTrace is called and the data appears in the respective table. If everything works fine with this code, you can then understand why your code doesn't work. I wish I could help you more, but I really do not have the time for that now.

Please share the code in text format and also share the LogApplication

I am able to log Traces to Application Insights which are seen in Azure Web Job.
Web Job Logs:

Application Insights Transaction Search:

Log Traces:


I have configured the code related to Application Insights in Program.cs file itself.
As you have the custom Logger you can add the same in LoggingEngine class or continue with Program.cs file.

I have referred this MSDoc to configure ApplicationInsights in Console App.

Instead of AddLogging, use ConfigureLogging section.

My Program.cs file:
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main()
        {
            var builder = new HostBuilder();            
            builder.ConfigureLogging((context, b) =>
            {
                b.AddConsole();   
                //b.AddFilter("Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting", LogLevel.None);
                //b.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Information);
                string ConnString = "InstrumentationKey=****;IngestionEndpoint=https://****.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://****.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/;ApplicationId=****";
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConnString))
                {
                    b.AddApplicationInsightsWebJobs(o => o.ConnectionString = ConnString);
                }
            });
            builder.ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
            {
                b.AddAzureStorageQueues();
            });
            var host = builder.Build();
            using (host)
            {
                var logger = host.Services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
                logger.LogInformation("Log Information from Progarm.cs..");
                logger.LogWarning("Warning Message");
                logger.LogDebug("Debug Message");
                logger.LogInformation("Application stopped.");

                await host.RunAsync();

            }
        }
    }
}


You can either use Instrumentation key or Connection String.

 b.AddApplicationInsightsWebJobs(o => o.InstrumentationKey = instrumentationKey);


In the deployed Azure App Service, Enable the Application Insights.



Do I need to enable Profiler to be able to see console writes?


For basic logs and traces, no need to enable the profiler.If you want additional Info, then you can enable it under AppService => Application Insights.



Thanks so much for your detailed reply
